# How do we write a decorator which forces a class to inherit from some other class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

Normally, we have one class inherit from another as follows:

```python
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    """
        ChildClass  is a subclass of ParentClass
        ParentClass is a superclass of ChildClass
    """
    pass
```

That is fine for most applications.

However, how would we write a decorator which forces one class to inherit from another?

```python
class SuperClass:
    def __str__(self):
        return "used SuperClass.__str__ INHERRITED FROM SUPER CLASS"
    @classmethod
    def force_inherit_from_super_class(cls, subclass):
        # should have some more code in here somewhere  
        return subclass 

#############################################################

class ChildClass1:
    pass

@SuperClass.force_inherit_from_super_class
class ChildClass2:
    pass

@SuperClass.force_inherit_from_super_class
class ChildClass3:
    def __str__(self):
        return "using ChildClass3.__str__. I HAVE OVERRIDDEN __str__"

obj1 = ChildClass1()
obj2 = ChildClass2()
obj3 = ChildClass3()

print("obj1...", str(obj1)) # should use object.__str__()
print("obj2...", str(obj2)) # should use SuperClass.__str__()
print("obj3...", str(obj3)) # should use ChildClass3.__str__()
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that - the decorator applies _after_ the class has already been created, where the parent(s) and mro have been determined, so you're too late.  (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: @wim you can use `type(class_name, bases, class_attributes)` to create a new class. That is, a class decorator can return a modified copy of the class. `new_class = type(old_class.__name__, old_class.__bases__, old_class.__dict__)`. We can edit `__bases__` so that the new_class inherits from the class of our choice.

Answer (score 0):

Like @wim commented, a class decorator is applied to a class object after it has been created, by which time its base classes are already decided and cannot be altered.

A workaround would be to make the decorator create a new class instead based on the given class object, using its name and class members:

```
class SuperClass:
    @classmethod
    def force_inherit_from_super_class(cls, subclass):
        return type(subclass.__name__, (cls,), dict(vars(subclass)))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/OnlyCompetentDeletion